# issues with date conversion, using rails 3.0.7 and ruby 1.9.2

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, date, jquery-ui-datepicker, ruby-1.9.2

i am using datepicker to insert date on my form, which of course returns date to the controller as a string.
the issue is when I try to convert this string to date, I get an error "invalid date"

`Date.parse(params[:abc][:date])`

To verify if  I'm doing it right, I wrote the following ruby program:

`string_date = "06/18/2011"` 
`date = Date.parse(string_date)` 
`puts date`

This works perfectly fine.  But when I try the same thing in my rails controller, it gives invalid date error.

please help.

Comment: its a model form, where :abc is the form object and date is a date field in the form (jquery datepicker)

Comment: params[:abc][:date] holds the value of date selected from datepicker.  so for instance if I select today's date (6/21/2011), params[:abc][:date] will contain the string "06/21/2011".
I tried printing this date value from my controller and noticed two things.  It prints the correct value when I do a  `puts params[:abc][:date]` and 
when the value is actually stored in the table abc, its blank.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When I do this in my Rails 3.1 console:

```
date = Date.parse("06/18/2011")
```

I get an "ArgumentError: invalid date" exception. However, it works fine with an [ISO-8601 date](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO8601#Dates):

```
date = Date.parse('2011-06-18')
```

So perhaps you're having a locale problem. Your script could be using your standard locale setting (which is probably some US locale judging by the date format) but your server is probably using something else.

Try changing the jQuery [datepicker date format](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#option-dateFormat) to something standard and unambiguous by adding this:

```
dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
```

to the datepicker's options. The datepicker's default is `'mm/dd/yy'` and Ruby's [Date class](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/date/rdoc/classes/Date.html#M000358) doesn't like seem to like it without a special locale setting.

Comment: @rrb: Sorry for the delay, I should have thought of the "format and locale" issue earlier. But, hey, fixed is fixed and now you can do more interesting things. You're probably better off using the ISO date format internally (always) and converting that format to and from other formats only at the edges.

Comment: better late than never :), so thank you!

hey, can you please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6443751/issues-with-getting-paperclip-to-play-nice-with-heroku-and-s3-using-rails-3-0-7

i've got some issues with heroku, paperclip and amazon s3

Comment: Changing the format of the datepicker to a non ambiguous format was actually the best idea for me, instead of trying to convert dates, which was a pain... Thanks :)